# How to know when to free memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, malloc, constants

So I'm running into a problem for a homework assignment- because `getApple` is const, I can't set `locallyAllocated = false`, which means whenever `getApple` is called with an apple instantiated and freed in some other program, my destructor attempts to free the memory and throws a double free error. What am I doing wrong, and how could I fix it? Note: the functions, their parameters and signatures have to be the way they are for our assignment. Thanks so much!

```
class poop
{

Apple localApple;
bool locallyAllocated;
void* pointer;

public:
    poop(const Apple &apple)
    {
        //Set our local apple to the apple in the provided address
        localApple = apple;
        locallyAllocated = false;
    }
    poop(string descr)
    {
        localApple.description = descr;
        pointer = maloc(sizeof(localApple);
        localApple.pointer = pointer
        locallyAllocated = true;
    }
    ~poop()
    {
        if(locallyAllocated)
        {
                //This throws a double free error if "getApple" is ever called
            free(pointer);
        }
    }
    void getApple(Apple* apple) const
    {
        if(apple)
        {
            //Copies our local apple into the address of the given apple
            //Because this function is "const", i can't do anything like set "locallyAllocated" to false
            *apple = localApple
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best class name ever! Also, least ironic comment ever.

Comment: You can look up the keyword `mutable`.

Comment: You can copy an apple if you want to free its memory in another class. But it's better to avoid freeng memory outside of a class that allocated it

Comment: What happens if the class is copied?

Answer (score 0):

You have some unsafe stuff going on here.. particularly:

```
poop(const Apple &apple)
{
    //Set our local apple to the apple in the provided address
    localApple = apple;
    locallyAllocated = false;
}
```

This means someone could probably free `apple.pointer` from under you, which means your `localApple.pointer` would be invalid.  You should do the alloc in that method too and memcpy data around.

However, there's a bigger problem here... you're not actually even using `.pointer`.  Do you even need to allocate anything?  What is your intent of pointer?

If you're happy with your class as is, you should check out the [mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `locallyAllocated` as `mutable` you will be able to change its value in const methods. Another worst solution would be to store `locallyAllocated` as a dynamically allocated boolean.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This has effectively solved the problem! The code is still throwing a "malloc() memory corruption" error now, but I suspect that has to do with something else I've goofed. Regardless thanks for your help!

Comment: @NateAnonymous: Do not solve problems with the `mutable`-hammer. You're shooting yourself in the foot, and it will start hurting when it's too late.

Comment: @bitmask: Ignoring issues with the design in general, isn't this the sort of situation where you would use mutable ? You want to change something in the class, that you expect to have no visible affect outside the class.

Comment: @bitmask Fair enough. I have a feeling when I finally understand memory enough to properly rework this I won't have to use mutable anymore.

Comment: @Kindread: Yes, but the design of C++ offers you a hint in some cases where you are doing something wrong. This is one such instance. The solution is to rethink the design. If you are using one of the potentially dangerous features (like `mutable`) chances are this is due to bad design hidden somewhere in the code (not always, though).

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to advise you to use shared pointers

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

However, if you do need to track the allocation yourself, you should make locallyAllocated mutable. In laymans terms, this means the member can be changed even in a method marked as const ( it allows you to maintain logical const while breaking 'physical' const ).

Comment: [Don't use cplusplus.com.](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=programmers.stackexchange&question=88241&printer=false&linktohome=true)

Answer (score 0):

To me, your problem seems to be that several apples are supposed to share the same object, pointed to by `Apple::pointer`. This, however, is not made explicit in your code. **That**'s the problem.

There is not the ultimate rule for memory management that fits everywhere. However, there are ways to reflect your *shared ownership* of the object pointed to by `Apple::pointer` (I assume that's an apple, too, given its size?).

- One thing you could do is write a proper copy constructor `Apple::Apple(Apple const&)` which takes care of duplicating the pointed to object.
- If you want to keep the shared ownership, use an [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of a raw pointer. This will take the responsibility to delete the pointed to object off your shoulders. "The last to leave closes the door."

Note that your `locallyAllocated` member is a very simplified version of smart pointers.